# Am I using java.time correctly, here? It seems like the old API would be easier

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I haven't used the `java.time` API very much because mostly my work involves capturing, storing, and displaying dates and times without manipulating them in any way. But occasionally, I have to do something like:

- Get the date 30 days in the past

I've also decided that, based upon other unrelated experiences, humans tend to consider "30 days in the past" to *actually* mean "the start of the day 30 days in the past" not just "now minus `30*24*60*60*1000` milliseconds in the past" which is super-easy to do with just System.currentTimeMillis and arithmetic.

So my requirement is:

- Get the date 30 days in the past, at the beginning of the day in my time zone

If I were to do this with the old API, I would do this:

```
TimeZone zone = ...; // However I get my time zone
Locale locale = ...; // However I get my locale
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(zone, locale);
// Reset to midnight
now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
// Now go back 30 days
now.add(Calendar.DAY, -30);
// done
```

Aside from the repeated calls to blank-out the time part of the `Calendar`, it's pretty straightforward. It uses only 3 classes, and two of them are the `TimeZone` and `Locale` classes, only one of which is really necessary (`TimeZone`).

This time around, I decided to use `java.time` because, well, it's "better." I really don't know my way around it, so I did a lot of internet searching to figure out how to do various things, and I finally came up with the code below. Isn't this supposed to be "easier?"

```
TimeZone zone = ...; // However I get my time zone
ZoneId zid = zone.toZoneId(); // Convert to new kind of time zone
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now(zid);
date = date.minus(Period.ofDays(30)); // Rewind 30 days
date = date.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
Instant instant = date.toInstant(); // Convert to Instant for comparisons
```

Now I'm using *6* different classes. Okay, 2 of them are constant-type things so we can ignore them. I have to use `Instant` because all the dates I have to use for comparison are `java.util.Date`, and `Instant` is the class that bridges all the gaps.

Is the problem that this is a "simple problem" and `java.time` is intended to solve problems that are far more complicated?

Comment: Do you really need the time of day? Can't the calculation be zoneless? If the date now is 31 May, 30 days ago it would be May 1st. Why are times involved in it at all?

Comment: For starters, to get your time zone as a modern `ZoneId`, don’t go the detour via the old and poorly designed `TimeZone` class. Use for example `ZoneId.systemDefault()` or `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")`. And while I agree that `Instant` is the natural bridge in this case, it isn’t really necessary since there’s also a two-way bridge between `ZonedDateTime` and `GregoriaCalendar`.

Comment: Which more clearly conveys that you want the time now, `Calendar.getInstance(zone, locale)` or `ZonedDateTime.now(zid)`? Which more clearly conveys that you are subtracting 30 days, `now.add(Calendar.DAY, -30);` or `date.minusDays(30)`? To me the question is not so much how many classes you use as how easy it is to read and understand your code.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have user-preferred time zones already as `TimeZone` objects everywhere in the code. I could either convert using String names or directly, but it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Good question. How can I compare a zoneless e.g. `LocalDate` object with `java.util.Date`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, Fair, but then when counting 6 classes, one of them comes from using the old classes, not from using the modern ones. Your conversion, `zone.toZoneId()`, is the idiomatic one.

Comment: You don't compare with `java.util.Date`, as this is not part of your question. You stop using `java.util.Date` altogether (and convert SQL Dates to LocalDate if you need to, as they really were supposed to be LocalDate anyway)

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well, my comparison with `java.util.Date` _was_ a part of the original question, in the second-to-last paragraph. I have 20 years of existing code that I'm not about to re-write just so I can avoid a conversion to `Instant` in this one specific case.

Answer (score 8):

> Get the date 30 days in the past

sounds like

`java.time.LocalDate.now().minusDays(30)`

Comment: I believe this will get me midnight at the start of 30 days ago _in UTC_ and not in my local time zone, correct?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz No, `LocalDate` represents a date-only value. No time-of-day, no time zone, no offset-from-UTC. Reading [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) will help you enormously.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz If you really need the date *and time at midnight*, not just the date, you can do `ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().minusDays(30), LocalTime.of(0, 0), ZoneId.systemDefault())`.

Comment: @BasilBourque [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#now()) agrees with @ChristopherSchultz . `LocalDate.now()` uses the default timezone to determine what the current date is. However one can pass a ZoneId.

Comment: @MikeFHay No, your comment misunderstands that of Christopher Schultz. The Schultz comment says `LocalDate` represents the start of a day as seen in UTC. That is completely incorrect. The **`LocalDate` class contains no time zone**, no offset. A `LocalDate` is ambiguous with regard to time-of-day. Ex: For a date of 2022-12-25, we have no way of knowing if you mean Christmas in Tokyo Japan or Christmas in Montreal Québec, two blocks of time that occur many hours apart. Using default time zone or passing `ZoneId`, to which you refer, is an *entirely different* issue: determining current date.

Comment: @MikeFHay Don't take my word for it. (a) Reread the Javadoc. (b) Look at [the source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java) as implemented in OpenJDK. The only member fields you will find in `LocalDate` are three integers: `int year`, `short month`, and `short day`.  You’ll find no time-of-day, nor will you find time zone or offset, as part of the state of a `LocalDate`. Just year, month, day — nothing more.

Comment: I think I confused things by being, well, wrong. When I said "_in UTC_" what I really should have said was "if I turn this into a timestamp I can use for comparison, I'll have to use a time zone, and if I don't use a specific time zone, I'll get UTC" which I _thought_ was correct. It's possible I'll get the default time zone on the machine which is almost always worthless.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of the multiple different classes in `java.time` is exactly to model many of the things you mentioned in your question.

> humans tend to consider "30 days in the past" to actually mean "the start of the day 30 days in the past"

Right, you don't care about the time, so you don't need a `DateTime`, just a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate prev = LocalDate.now().minusDays(30);
```

If you have to convert to an `Instant`, then you need to specify a timezone.

```
Instant asInstant = prev.atStartOfDay​(zone).toInstant();
```

However if you don't care about the time then you probably shouldn't be converting to Instant, just stick with `LocalDate`.

> I have to use Instant because all the dates I have to use for comparison are java.util.Date

`Date` includes a time part. Are you truncating those to the start of day as well? One way to do that and get back a `LocalDate` is:

```
date.toInstant().atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: I need to take `java.util.Date` objects and compare them to ... whatever I come up with using `java.time` to find my benchmark date (30 days ago). I could convert those `java.util.Date` objects to `java.time` objects but I don't see any particular need to do so, given that `java.util.Date` is already willing to compare against `Instant`.

Comment: I don't really care about the time part of the dates I have, but truncating them is just more work that doesn't matter (any part of a day will be "after" midnight -- or more precisely _not before_ midnight). As long as the benchmark date is "at midnight" then the precision of the other date doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;        // Date varies around the globe by time zone.
LocalDate todayTokyo = LocalDate.now( zTokyo ) ;   // Capture the current date as seen in a particular time zone.
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfDateInTokyo = todayTokyo.atStartOfDay( zTokyo ) ;  // Determine the first moment of that date in that zone.
Instant firstMomentOfDateInTokyoAsSeenInUtc = firstMomentOfDateInTokyo.toInstant() ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Waohh1).

> 2022-05-24
>
> 2022-05-24T00:00+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
>
> 2022-05-23T15:00:00Z

## Details

### Date only

As shown in correct [Answer by Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72353474/642706), if you want the current date without a time-of-day and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
```

The [`now`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#now()) method implicitly uses your JVM's current default time zone to determine the date. Be aware that for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. Right now it is "tomorrow" in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously "yesterday" in Toledo Ohio US.

Best to [specify](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#now(java.time.ZoneId)) your desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate todayTokyo = LocalDate.now( zTokyo ) ;
```

### Date with time-of-day & zone

If you want the first moment of the day on that date as seen in that time zone, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00. Some dates in some time zones may start at another time such as 01:00.  Let *java.time* determine the first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime firstMomentOfDateInTokyo = todayTokyo.atStartOfDay( zTokyo ) ;
```

If you want to see what that moment simultaneously looks like with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant firstMomentOfDateInTokyoAsSeenInUtc = firstMomentOfDateInTokyo.toInstant() ;
```

### Avoid legacy classes

You said:

> Instant is the class that bridges all the gaps.

You should not be mixing the legacy date-time classes with the modern *java.time* classes. The old classes are *terrible*, bloody awful, a masterclass in how *not* to do object-oriented programming.

If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, convert to-and-fro using new `to…`/`from…`/`valueOf` conversion methods added to the old classes. But do not mix legacy & modern within your logic.

> Is the problem that this is a "simple problem" and java.time is intended to solve problems that are far more complicated?

No, *java.time* is appropriate to all business and personal oriented date-time work (perhaps not all scientific or academic work). The legacy classes are a disaster that should be avoided entirely.

The *java.time* classes are actually utterly simple in the entities they represent. You just need to get real clear on what your needs are, what goals are you trying to accomplish.

- Represent a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds: `Instant`
- Represent a date, just a date, no time, no zone, and therefore inherently ambiguous: `LocalDate`
- Represent a moment as seen in a particular time zone: `ZonedDateTime`.
- Represent a moment as seen in a particular offset from UTC: [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). This class maps to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in standard SQL.
- Represent a date with time of day but lacking the context of a time zone or offset and therefore ambiguous within a range of about 26-27 hours: `LocalDateTime`. This class maps to `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in standard SQL.

The legacy classes have equivalents for only two of those: (a) `java.util.Date` is replaced by `Instant`, and (b) `java.util.Calendar` (well, actually [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)) is replaced by `ZonedDateTime`. The legacy classes neglected to represent a date-only, a date with offset, and a date and time without zone/offset. The `java.sql.Date` class *pretends* to represent a date-only, but does not. And `java.sql.Timestamp`, well, I never could figure out what that beast was trying to do.

FYI, an offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind UTC. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region, as decided by their politicians.